# Install luasql.oci8 without the use of luarocks in my debian 11 bullseyes

Tags: oci8, luasql

lua version I am having is lua5.2.4
OS is debian 11 bullseye
I want to install luasql.oci8 in my debian 11
I am already having luasql.mysql, luasql.postgres and so on .
I have installed oci8.so file and provided in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/luasql/oci8.so`
but still when I am using in my lua script like
local env = luasql.oci8()

its giving me a error

> Oracle env : [ LuaSQL: couldn't create environment ]

can anyone please tell me on how to install luasql.oci8